# Swift: How to set max/min to pan gesture?

Tags: swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Note: I already tried with the other answers I found and nothing worked for me.

I need to set a screen limit to a UIView I can drag around my main view (so that I can't drag it outside the view). Plus I'd like to know how to have this screen limit adapt to different devices.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
if let view = recognizer.view {
    view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
}
recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: A problem in setting the region where the user is allowed to move an object with `UIPanGesture` is that they will not be able to move it once its position goes out of bounds.  So what are you going to do about that?

Comment: In the `changed` state of the gesture, just declare the conditions that you want the view's frame to adhere to. For example, if the view's frame's y-origin is ever less than 0, then it is equal to 0. This does not interrupt the gesture itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following shows how to pan a `UILabel` control over the main view of the view controller (`UIViewController`) and how to restrict its pan movement within the visible boundaries of the latter.  Note that the status bar is assumed to be visible.  So the top boundary is determined by the height of the status bar.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - Variables

    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    // MARK: - IBAction

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    @objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        let statusFrame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame

        if let senderView = sender.view {
            if senderView.frame.origin.x < 0.0 {
                senderView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: senderView.frame.origin.y)
            }
            if senderView.frame.origin.y < statusFrame.height {
                senderView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: senderView.frame.origin.x, y: statusFrame.height)
            }
            if senderView.frame.origin.x + senderView.frame.size.width > view.frame.width {
                senderView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width - senderView.frame.size.width, y: senderView.frame.origin.y)
            }
            if senderView.frame.origin.y + senderView.frame.size.height > view.frame.height {
                senderView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: senderView.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.height - senderView.frame.size.height)
            }
        }

        if let centerX = sender.view?.center.x, let centerY = sender.view?.center.y {
            sender.view?.center = CGPoint.init(x: centerX + translation.x , y: centerY + translation.y)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! If you do it on storyboard just change "shared" in "recognizer" and it will be fine